# NSArray and NIL values. How to return the number ("count") of non-NIL values the array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsarray

I have two questions regarding an NSArray:

- How can I add nil values to the array? Would be adding `[NSNull
  null]` be correct?
- What would be the best code to
  return the number (count) of nil and non-nil values of this array in
  your view?

Thank you!!

Comment: If you need to count how many elements you have in a collection use the NSCountedSet class instead of NSArray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add `nil` to an `NSArray`, so you will have to use `[NSNull null]` instead as you said.

You can count the number of `nil` (`NSNull`) items this way:

```
NSIndexSet *nilIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return obj == [NSNull null];
}];

NSUInteger count = nilIndexes.count;
```

Answer (score 4):

- You cannot add nil value, so use `[NSNull null]`.
- Make a category of NSArray and iterate through it counting `null` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from Mike Ash [MACollectionUtilities](https://github.com/mikeash/MACollectionUtilities/blob/master/MACollectionUtilities.h#L23)

```
#define ARRAY(...) ([NSArray arrayWithObjects: IDARRAY(__VA_ARGS__) count: IDCOUNT(__VA_ARGS__)])
```